# how to display two data item in One list view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Hello guys i have one of the problem in android development.i'm still develop an android app.So i am facing a problem of the android listview.

my problem is ,i want to display two data items in on the one listview .
like this :

```
 Recipt No :Date
 001       :2017/11/30
```

so now i use Arrayadapter for load one data element.
but now i want load two data in the list view

below i put my java code of load one data in the list view.

```
 public void showList()
{
    String[] ides = new String[de1.size()];     

    for (int i = 0; i < de1.size(); i++) {

        ides[i] = de1.get(i).getId().toString();



    }
   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(depositDetails.this,R.layout.depositlists,R.id.b,ides);


         listViewlist.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

xml code part

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.060000002">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Deposit Index"
                android:textColor="#c60a0a"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.037"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewProduct"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/ButtonCol"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.03"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewProduct"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.555" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create a class for your adapter instead of `ArrayAdapter` and define the necessary properties within that.. You can refer this **[example here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example)**

Comment: you need to use custom layout and adapter for items. for more info visit **[Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

Context context;
ArrayList<User> userArrayList;
public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
    super(context, R.layout.depositlists, userArrayList);
    this.context=context;
    this.userArrayList=userArrayList;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.depositlists, parent, false);
    }

    User user = getItem(position);


    TextView b = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    TextView Status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Status);

    b.setText(user.getReciptNo());
    Status.setText(user.getDate());

    return convertView;
}
}


Replace showList method  

public void showList()
{
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < de1.size(); i++) {

        users.add(new User(i,de1.get(i).getId().toString()));

    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(depositDetails.this,users);

    listViewlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


Add User Class


public class User {
String  ReciptNo;
String Date;

public User(String reciptNo, String date) {
    ReciptNo = reciptNo;
    Date = date;
}

public String getReciptNo() {
    return ReciptNo;
}

public void setReciptNo(String reciptNo) {
    ReciptNo = reciptNo;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}
}
```